# Load file into input stream and use scanf()

Tags: c++, scanf

I am very new to c++.

I read some code samples of some experienced c++ coders, and noticed that they ran a file starting with scanf, that read through a large input.

However, they didn't use any specified ifstream to read in a file, they seemed to just run scanf as if this entire input .txt file was already in the stream.

Is this because they are using some special IDE where you can load in input file into the standard stream?

I am simply trying to run their code to duplicate something they are doing, but I need some way to read in a 5000+ line text file and then run scanf on it.

How do I do this. I'm not using any sort of IDE, just notepad++. If someone recommends an IDE, i'll take it, but otherwise would just like advice on how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: fscanf is a legacy function from C.

Comment: You lie. There are no "experienced c++ coders" who use `scanf`.

Comment: I don't know if I lie, I simply am too "unexperienced" to know that. But really I believe it would depend on the purpose. This person who used it got first place in a coding contest with 45,000 participants, so he is somewhat experienced, I would suppose. His goal was minimum lines of code on a simple input, so perhaps in that context it would be a good tool to use. Then again, I can be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, if they're still using `scanf()`, they are *not* experienced C++ programmers. If they were experienced, they would be using the C++ I/O facilities rather than the legacy C ones.

Having said that, you can quite easily use the functions accepting standard input (either `scanf()` or `cin`) if you can do redirection on the program, with lines like:

```
myProg <myInputFile.txt
someOtherProgWhichProducesOutput | myProg
```

This "attaches" the file `myInputFile.txt` to the standard input of the `myProg` program, or takes the output from another program and feeds it to the input of `myProg`, and is what makes UNIX and its brethren (including Windows in this context, since it too has redirection and pipelines) so powerful, allowing you to string together complicated pipelines from relatively simple commands.

Comment: Since he's using Notepad++ I assume he's on Windows.

Comment: Yes, and both input redirection and piping are available under Windows as well, so I'll make that clear.